# Is there a way to optimize the upload of huge json files to mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am working on a project where I need to use a database in order to better manage my data, and so I decided to use MongoDB for performance reasons.
After setting everything up, I made a script that uses a pipeline to download a zip file, unpack it, grab the XLS file inside and convert the content to JSON (so I can manage it in my code/database). Everything works very well except when I am uploading every JSON part into MongoDB, the download speed decreases exponentially, and seems like the query is blocking the event loop.
I had the idea to use `Promise.all()` to optimize my queries but the problem with it is that the array will grow a lot ending up in a memory exception (doing checks for array size on every data callback may also add further overhead to the execution).
That's my code:

```
const updateCatalog = async () => {
server.log.info('Updating catalog...');
const progressBar = new cliProgress.SingleBar({}, cliProgress.Presets.shades_classic);

const parser = Papa.parse(NODE_STREAM_INPUT, {
    header: false,
    fastMode: true
});

const database = client.db('bonnie');
const collection = database.collection('catalog');

progress(request(ZIP_URI)).on('progress', (state: RequestProgressState) => {
    progressBar.update(Math.floor(state.percent * 100));
}).on('response', () => progressBar.start(100, 0))
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on('entry', (entry: unzip.Entry) => {
        entry.pipe(parser).on('data', async (data: Array<string>) => {
            await collection.insertOne({
                embedUrl: data[0],
                thumbnailUrl: data[1],
                thumbnailUrls: data[2].split(';'),
                title: data[3],
                tags: data[4].split(';'),
                categories: data[5].split(';'),
                authors: data[6].split(';'),
                duration: parseInt(data[7]) ?? 0,
                views: parseInt(data[8]) ?? 0,
                likes: parseInt(data[9]) ?? 0,
                dislikes: parseInt(data[10]),
                thumbnailHdUrl: data[11],
                thumbnailHdUrls: data[12].split(';')
            }); 
        }).on('end', () => {
            progressBar.stop();
            server.log.info('Catalog updated');
        }).on('error', (err: any) => { client.close(); }); 
});
}
```

The same issue with memory exception will obviously happen with mongo Bulks too.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, is the whole dataset contained in a single XLS file? How large is the file?

Comment: @KenHung The dataset is about ~15GB and it is contained in a single XLS file, my code parses every row and transforms it into a JSON string, what I want to achieve is to insert that JSON string into MongoDB without slowing down the parser I created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file seems too big to fit into memory, causing memory exceptions. You need to save the file on disk first. Then you could try command line tools like [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) from MongoDB. You will need to convert the XLS file to a CSV file, or JSON Lines, and then import it.

If you want to stick with NodeJS, you then need:

1. Load the file partially (to prevent the memory exception)
2. Use [collection.insertMany()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/insertMany/) to insert the loaded data